# Name for largest subset of image whose preimage is contained in the original set?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Given a function $f:X \to Y$ and a subset $A \subseteq X$ let $A^*$ be the largest subset of $f(A)$ such that $f^{-1}(A^*) \subseteq A$. Is there a name for $A^*$?

Comment: Your $A^*$ will fail to exist often (as an example, when $f$ is constant).

Comment: @MartinArgerami It would be empty set then.